# C++ Concepts with multiple template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

Bjarne Stroustrup recently published a [report](http://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf) on C++ Concepts where he mentions something that seemed surprising to me. The example (in Section 7.1) uses "shorthand template notation" and essentially goes like this:

```
void foo1(auto x,auto y);                // x and y may have different types  (1)
void foo2(SomeConcept x,SomeConcept y);  // x and y must have the same type   (2)
```

To me personally, this seems *very* counter-intuitive; in fact, I would expect foo2 to accept values x,y of different types as long as the respective types satisfy SomeConcept. Note that the programmer can always explicitly specify his intent by writing one of the following:

```
template <SomeConcept T> void foo2(T x, T y);                   // (3)
template <SomeConcept T1,SomeConcept T2> void foo2(T1 x,T2 y);  // (4)
```

Intuitively, I would expect the shorthand notation from (2) to be equivalent to (4) and thus be more consistent with the meaning of the unconstrained template (1). Can somebody shed light on the matter and explain the rationale behind this design decsision?

Some remarks:

- afaik, generic lambdas (in C++14) already allow a syntax similar to (1). Hence, consistency dictates that (1) should accept input variables with different types, since generic lambdas do that.
- Stroustrup mentions the classical "iterator pair" in the context of such templates. However, I believe that this is a fairly weak argument since (i) this is just one use-case and (ii) afaik, C++17 introduces (iterator, sentinel) pairs, which forces generic code to use two different types anyway.

Comment: Agreed that it's counter-intuitive. I really really want *abbreviated syntax*, as long as it allows different types for the same concepts.

Comment: Note that papers mainly represent the author's views, not necessarily that of the committee. And I think the committee is far from unanimous regarding Concepts (as you can see from looking at past mailings). What will ultimately happen remains to be seen; what you are looking for are committee motions that have passed.

Comment: The same rule is stated in the current version of the Concepts TS (§8.3.5, p.22): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4641.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a quick update for those who tagged this question or find it on Google.

The issue discussed here was resolved---apparently silently---before the C++ standards meeting in Jacksonville, March 2018. To quote from [Botond's trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-jacksonville-march-2018/):

> As an aside, one topic that seems to have been settled without much discussion was the question of *independent resolution* vs. *consistent resolution*; that is, if you have two uses of the same concept in an AFT (as in `void foo(Number, Number);`), are they required to be the same concrete type (“consistent”), or two potentially different types that both model the concept (“independent”). The Concepts TS has consistent resolution, but many people prefer independent resolution. I co-authored a paper arguing for independent resolution a while back; that sentiment was subsequently reinforced by another paper, and also in a section of the `Sortable{S}` proposal. Somewhat to my amusement, the topic was never actually formally discussed and voted on; the idea of independent resolution just seemed to slowly, over time, win people over, such that by this meeting, it was kind of treated as a done deal, that any AFT proposal going into C++20 will, in fact, have independent resolution.

Comment: And it should be noted that the version actually approved at the San Diego meeting follows through on this: each parameter is independent of all others. As it should be.

Comment: What happened was that the `void f(Concept x);` syntax was [removed entirely](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0696r1.html) (influencing the eventual [wording paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0734r0.pdf)) and then [reintroduced](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1141r2.html) with `auto` and (tacitly, indeed) “independent resolution”.

Comment: @NicolBolas so what happens when you try to forward both parameters to another function and must explicitly state the type, now having 2 different types of the same name? Does it "just work"?

Comment: @Gukki5: ... I don't understand what you're talking about. Why do you have to explicitly state a type? If the destination template requires both types to be the same, then why aren't your function parameters declared so that they produce the same type? Remember: abbreviated template syntax is not intended to be used for *everything*; you can always write it out long-form.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest paper I could find that mentions the terse syntax in the context of the current Concepts proposal is [N3580](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf), which in §6.2.2 provides this rationale:

> What if we need two argument types of the same concept? Consider
>
> ```
> void sort(Ran p, Ran q);
> ```
>
> For this to make sense, `p` and `q` must be of the same type, and that is the rule. By default, if you use the same constrained parameter name for two arguments, the types of those arguments must be the same. We chose to make repeated use of a constrained parameter name imply “same type” because that (in most environments) is the most common case and the aim here is to optimize for
>   terse notation of the simplest case. Also, a constrained parameter is the name
>   of a type, and having two type names refer to different types in the same scope
>   would cause chaos.

Tony van Eerd and Boton Ballo have a proposal to change this meaning: [P0464](http://wg21.link/p0464). The paper provides two arguments in support of the current meanings, one similar to the one Sutton et al make, and one orthogonal:

> **Frequency of use**
>   It can be argued that you don't often want a function that takes two arguments of potentially different types satisfying the same concept without having an additional relationship between the two types.
>
> **Interaction with definition checking**
>   It can also be argued that this change will encourage template authors to write under-constrained templates, because they will opt to use the terse `R foo(ConceptName, ConceptName);`  form even in cases where in there should be an additional constraint on the parameter types. A proliferation of under-constrained templates will make the introduction of definition checking harder, because an under-constrained template will not pass definition checking.

---

I'm not familiar with any other argument in favor of the current syntax, but if you are, feel free to email Tony and Botond for inclusion into their paper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually found the proposal by Botond a while after my original question, and I hope that it gains the support of the committee. For me personally, the main argument is consistency with the 'auto' syntax, but it appears that Botond already states this in his proposal.