# Concept with multiple template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to use C++20 concepts, to start familiarizing with them.
I feel pretty comfortable with easy concepts, for example with the standard concept `movable` I can write something like this (in all examples I suppose I'm `using namespace std` and I included `<concepts>` and any other header needed):

```
template<movable T>
int foo (T obj);
```

And be sure that when this function is called the passed object `obj` can be moved.
I can write this even in a longer form:

```
template<typename T>
requires movable<T>
int foo (T obj);
```

And the result would be the same (I think).

But now let's look at another concept such as `same_as`. `same_as` takes 2 templates parameter (the 2 types to compare), so I can write:

```
template<typename T>
requires same_as<T, string>
int bar (T obj);
```

And now T is `string`. But How can I write it in the shorter form? I tried, and I can write this (as I intuitively expected):

```
template<same_as<string> T>
int bar (T obj);
```

**But what is the formal rule behind this form?**

Is the *name* (`T`) of the function template parameter, entered as first argument of the concept template? Or maybe as last? I don't know, there is very little information about this topic. I mean, in this example it is irrelevant, because `same_as<A, B>` [is semantically equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) to `same_as<B, A>`, but there are for sure cases where the order matters.

---

*I know there are questions with similiar titles, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413381/c-concepts-with-multiple-template-arguments), but it asks a different thing.*

*These are the resources I tried to get information from, but failed: [cppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), [cppModernes](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-20-concepts-the-details), [open-std (I browsed years 2018, 2019 and 2020)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/) and [this post](https://omnigoat.github.io/2020/01/19/cpp20-concepts/).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But what is the formal rule behind this form?

The rule (that you correctly guessed your way into) is described in [[temp.param]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4):

> A *type-constraint* `Q` that designates a concept `C` can be used to constrain a contextually-determined type or template type parameter pack `T` with a *constraint-expression* `E` defined as follows.
>   If `Q` is of the form `C<A1, ⋯, An>`, then let `E′` be `C<T, A1, ⋯, An>`.
>   Otherwise, let `E′` be `C<T>`.
>   If `T` is not a pack, then `E` is `E′`, otherwise `E` is `(E′ && ...)`.
>   This *constraint-expression* `E` is called the *immediately-declared constraint* of `Q` for `T`.
>   The concept designated by a *type-constraint* shall be a type concept ([temp.concept]).

With examples in the subsequent paragraph:

> A *type-parameter* that starts with a *type-constraint* introduces the immediately-declared constraint of the *type-constraint* for the parameter.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C1 = true;
> template<typename... Ts> concept C2 = true;
> template<typename T, typename U> concept C3 = true;
>
> template<C1 T> struct s1;               // associates C1<T>
> template<C1... T> struct s2;            // associates (C1<T> && ...)
> template<C2... T> struct s3;            // associates (C2<T> && ...)
> template<C3<int> T> struct s4;          // associates C3<T, int>
> template<C3<int>... T> struct s5;       // associates (C3<T, int> && ...)
> ```
>
> — end example
>    ]

You can also think of `template <C T>` as being shorthand for `template <C<> T>`, and then the type parameter `T` just always slots into the first argument of the concept.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, I've been struggling since yesterday to find the formal confirmation of this rule. So the _name_ becomes the first parameter. I'll save the site you pointed me to, it's perfect and I never find it on my searches on Google. Thanks!

Comment: @Lapo Yep, that site is the HTML version of the latest C++ working draft. Good thing to refer to when you want to look up what the standard says (plus it's all nice and linked and everything).

Comment: Yes indeed, it's very well done. It's a shame it's never on the first pages of Google search. Very interesting discovery!